# How to insert code as code inside a document

Tags: php, html

```
<pre>
      Een PHP script kan overal in een document geplaatst worden. <br>
      een PHP script begint met: <code> ***<?php ?>*** </code>
    </pre>
```

I'm working on a little project for myself to try and make a documentation page,
Now everyone knows the basic echo 'hello world' inside of the PHP tags like so:

```
    <?php 
echo 'hello world'; 
?>
```

yet i have this in an HTML document and was wondering. Is there a way to display PHP code inside of HTML code? or do i need to approach this differently?
When i try this inside of the  or  tags it won't display the
'<' from ?php.
i have also read on MDN docs and it quotes:

*

"Use the  element or, if semantically adequate, the  element instead. Note that you will need to escape the '<' character as '<' to make sure it is not interpreted as markup."

*

Any help and advice is truly appreciated.

Comment: "Yet i wouldn't know how to escape with &lt." — You just type `&lt;` instead of typing `<`

Comment: oh i'm a dummy. But everything inside of &lt; and > is considered code inside of code?

Comment: `<` means "start a tag" but `&lt;` means "Display a less than sign". There is nothing "inside" `&lt;` and `>` because `&lt;` doesn't start anything for that to be inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities).
As per docs

> Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities

So basically you need to do this

```
<?php
echo htmlentities('<?php echo "hello world"; ?>');
?>
```

Working example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c7629280bdb7368e17f41643fed43675dd95fe89

Comment: &lt;?php 
echo &quot;hello world&quot;; 
?&gt; So is i wanted to display everything as code this is the correct way for html? or does the htmlentities do it for you?

Comment: Yes htmlentities encodes any string into a browser readable string. You may as well do `echo htmlentities('<script> alert("my name"); </script>');` and the browser will show the js tags instead of running them. Preserving format could be tricky but `pre` tags will do that for you